# Javascript to check from browser if app is installed or open app (ios)

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, app-store

Basically I want to provide in my page a link for the user to install or open my app.

1. In case (1) the user has the app already installed, the link (click
   action) will open the app.
2. In the case (2) where the user does not
   have the app, the link (click action) will redirect the user to the
   app store.

I've found a few answers to solve this problem using timeout.
However, during my tests, I've noticed that in case (1) the browser opens a popup modal which asks the user for confirmation.

> "Open in 'App Name'?"  Cancel or Open

And while this popup is visible, the timeout is still running, and what happens is that doesn't matter what the user answers here, the browser always redirects to the appstore because the timeout takes effect.

I am assuming that this user confirmation window is rather new when asking users to open an app from the browser and the current solutions here are not covering it.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: You can use universal links and smart banners

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Smart App Banners" and this official documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Basically you need to add a `<meta>` tag to your website.

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">`